# If two values have different data types, Java will automatically promote one of the values to the larger of the two data types?

Tags: java, downcast, upcasting

The rule says that if two values have different data types, Java will automatically promote one of the values to the larger of the two data types?

In the code below, the value assigned to y is larger than the value of x. Therefore, taking the rule into consideration, the printed value should be "Float" but instead it printed "Double. Can you please why it prints Double instead of Float?

```
    Double x = 3.21; 

    Float y = 4.1f;

    Object o  = (x*y);

    System.out.println( o.getClass().getSimpleName() ); // prints out Double
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Larger" does not refer to the ">" value, but (in a nutshell) to the data type that can hold more information, e.g. Double is preferred over Float and Long is preferred over Int.

This is documented here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2

Answer (score 1):

The values of the variables don't matter. Their types matter. `double` is an 8 bytes types and `float` is a 4 bytes type. Hence, to multiply a `double` and a `float`, you promote the variable of the smaller type (`float`) to the larger type (`double`).

If you are multiplying a `Double` with a `Float`, they will be unboxed to `double` and `float`. In order to multiply a `double` with a `float`, the `float` would be promoted to `double`, and `double` multiplication would take place.

Since the result is stored in an `Object`, the `double` result will be boxed to a `Double`.

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstood what "larger" means in the phrase "the larger of the two data types". If it had said "the larger of the two *values*", then your understanding would have been correct.

A large *data type* is one that takes up more memory. A `double` takes up 64 bits, while a `float` takes up 32 bits, so `double` is the larger data type.

Note that this behaviour (binary numeric promotion) only applies to numeric types and can't really be described with one single rule such as "If two values have different data types, Java will automatically promote one of the values to the larger of the two data types". For example, a `short` times a `byte` gives you an `int`. This is specified fully in the Java Language Specification.

For more info, see [section 5.6.2 in the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2).